# Insert sendo executado duas vezes

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho um código para quando se realizar um logout no sistema, ser registrado em uma tabela do banco de dados.

Eu chamo esse arquivo que faz o logout quando clico no botão sair e também quando fecho a janela no navegador.

O problema é que algumas vezes o INSERT faz a inserção dos registros duas vezes.

Não sei se o problema é o problema. Já tentei diversas maneira de corrigir isso, porém todas sem sucesso.

**Vou deixar os código abaixo:**

```js
//Código JavaScript para chamar o arquivo logout.php quando o navegador é fechado

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $.get("../banco/validador-de-login/logout.php", function(data) {
    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Arquivo logout.php -->

<?php

require_once("../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php");

session_start(); //iniciamos a sessão que foi aberta

require_once("../login-logout/login.php");

$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

//Esse IF verifica se a sessão está ativa. Só chama a função se a sessão está ativa. 
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{
pegarLogout($conecta, $usuario);

}
 
session_destroy(); //destruimos a sessão ;)
 
session_unset(); //limpamos as variaveis globais das sessões

/*aqui você pode redirecionar para uma determinada página*/
/*
echo "<script> document.location.href='../../index.php';</script>";
*/

header('location:../../index.php');

?>


  <!-- Arquivo login.php -->
  <!-- Arquivo que contém as funçõe que realizam o insert -->

  <?php

 
 /* Função para realizar o controle de login de usuários */
 function pegarLogin($conexao, $user)
 {
   
  $query_login = "INSERT INTO log(tipo_reg,horario,usuario,data) VALUES('LOGIN',CURTIME(),'$user',CURDATE())"; 
  $resultado_query_login =  mysqli_query($conexao, $query_login);

  if(!$resultado_query_login) /*Verifica se o resultado deu certo ou errado*/
  {
   /*Se deu erro, então exibe a mensagem do sql sobre o erro */
   die("Falha no registro do login: " . mysqli_error($conexao)); 
  }

  


  //echo "<BR> Concluído a atualização das atividades com sucesso. <BR> Quantidade de atividades atualizadas: " . $contador;
 }


 /* Função para realizar o controle de login de usuários */
 function pegarLogout($conexao_2, $user)
 {
   
  $query_login_2 = "INSERT INTO log(tipo_reg,horario,usuario,data) VALUES('LOGOUT',CURTIME(),'$user',CURDATE())"; 
  $resultado_query_login_2 =  mysqli_query($conexao_2, $query_login_2);

  if(!$resultado_query_login_2) /*Verifica se o resultado deu certo ou errado*/
  {
   /*Se deu erro, então exibe a mensagem do sql sobre o erro */
   die("Falha no registro do login: " . mysqli_error($conexao_2)); 
  } 
  
  //echo "<BR> Concluído a atualização das atividades com sucesso. <BR> Quantidade de atividades atualizadas: " . $contador;
 }



?>


    <!-- Botão de deslogar que fica no menu da página HTML -->

    <a class="text-light dropdown-item" href="../banco/validador-de-login/logout.php">Sair <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
```

**Imagem da tabela**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Reparem que é feito uma segunda inserção com o coluna que guarda o nome do usuário em branco.**

Não sei onde eu posso estar errando. 
Se puderem me ajudar, ficaria grato.

Comment: Se o cara clicar no botão "sair" e fechar a janela, não irá registrar 2x?

Comment: Acho que não, pois o script dessa função não é chamado no index.

Comment: @Sam, mentira. Verifiquei aqui e está executando o javascript também quando fecho no botão de "deslogar". Então está executando duas vezes.

Answer (score 1):

**Análise**

Nesse código:

```
//Esse IF verifica se a sessão está ativa. Só chama a função se a sessão está ativa. 
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{
  pegarLogout($conecta, $usuario);

}
```

Parece que a intenção é descobrir estado da sessão atual e prevenir uma chamada de logout baseado no estado atual da sessão. O porém é que esse código não faz isso, ou pelo menos ele não faz bem a tarefa a qual foi designado.
No [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-status.php) está especificado que `session_status()` é usada para retornar o status atual da sessão. Porém se `session_status()` for utilizado após a chamada da função `session_start()`, como é o caso, apenas informará se as sessões estão ou não habilitadas nas configurações.

Outra coisa é fato de mesmo você ter usado esse código:

```
session_destroy(); //destruimos a sessão ;)

session_unset(); //limpamos as variaveis globais das sessões
```

A variável superglobal `$_SESSION` ainda persiste, mesmo sem refrência, um id ou valores associados.
`session_destroy()` não elimina completa ou definitivamente a sessão. `session_destroy()` apenas elimina a referência `$_SESSION`, a sessão, temporariamente até a próxima chamada de `session_start()` onde a referência `$_SESSION`, a sessão, é retomada.

**Solução**

Só pela pergunta não dá para saber o que leva o código do logout a ser chamado duas vezes, mas o que dá para ser feito é criar condições para prevenir uma segunda chamada do logout usando a variável de sessão.

```
<!-- Arquivo logout.php -->

<?php

  require_once("../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php");

  session_start(); //<-- Retoma a referência para o superglobal $_SESSION

  require_once("../login-logout/login.php");

  // Verifica se o valor 'usuario' está definido no array $_SESSION
  if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        pegarLogout($conecta, $_SESSION['usuario']);    
  }


  //Libera os valores atualmente registradas na sessão. Chame antes de 
  //session_destroy.
  session_unset(); 

  //Não destrói a sessão ou cookie de sessão. Só invalida temporariamente a referência
  //para a superglobal $_SESSION. A referência pode ser retomada com `session_start()`
  session_destroy();

  header('location:../../index.php');

?>
```